# IE does not send Cookie to server

Tags: internet-explorer, session, cookies

I used method SetCookie from CInternetSession to create cookie and then open IE to access the same server. But IE does not send cookies which created by CInternetSession.
The folder where cookie file is stored is C:\Users\myname\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\INetCookies

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution.
Just turn off the protected mode and the cookies will be sent to server.